# Cannot find selector in browserless.io

Tags: html, node.js, chromium, puppeteer

In puppeteer, I am trying to get a `p` element in the page, which is dynamically created. Locally, I am launching a puppeteer instance by:

```
puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      timeout: 90000,
      args: [`--no-sandbox`, `--disable-setuid-sandbox`],
    });
```

I can reach the element in the page by:

```
await page.goto(URL);
await page.waitForSelector(`#selectorName`, {
  timeout: 90000,
});

const res = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const p = document.querySelector(`#selectorName`);
  return p.innerHTML;
});
```

I want to use browserless.io for my prod environment, so I am connecting to the instance as below, instead of launching Chromium locally:

```
puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint: wss://chrome.browserless.io?token=API_TOKEN })
```

However, the `waitForSelector` function in this setup gives timeout. The URL is the same and I checked that the page still opens the desired url (by `page.url()`) and the `p` element is still there when I open the page locally.  Do I need to get the selector in another way, when I render my page in browserless.io?

Comment: Why don't you want to assume that the p element would be there in, say, 5 seconds? And verify existence with `evaluate()` operation. If p is present, continue your flow, if don't - retry. After a few retries, stop the execution

Comment: I feel like 90 seconds is quite a lot, and it works locally anyway. I also debugged using browserless.io's website, and I see the selector being loaded there. This part is crucial for my website so I need to make this work, I cannot stop its execution.

Comment: Hi Ezgi. Can this be a issue with chrome.browserless.io timeout limit? I don't know it, but as it is a online service, it's reasonable to think that they have some time of internal timeout to things like 90 seconds. Try to run a docker instance passing the "CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=120000" parameter, like in https://docs.browserless.io/docs/docker.html#connection-timeout example, and see if this happens on your docker instance too. Don't forget to change the browserWSEndpoint to point to your por 3000 (if you use this port on your docker container).